# Пояснение — нужно два тире или одно?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пояснение

Нужно разобраться в знаках при пояснении. Везде пояснение, вставной конструкции нет и не будет!

`Вчера — в пятницу (—) я не пришëл, из-за того что был занят.`

Нужно в первом примере второе тире или нет? Кажется, да.

`Я не пришел вчера — в пятницу, (—) из-за того что был занят.`

А во втором? Пояснения двумя тире обособлябтся или одним? Если двумя, то поглощается ли второе тире запятой, требуемой второй частью предложения?

Comment: А сколько вам, Максим, летчонок?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр А вам зачем?)

Comment: По-кошачьи интересно.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Точный возраст говорить не хочу. Могу только сказать, что мне ещë нет 18. А вам сколько? По-объективному интересно.

Comment: I'm sixteen. Why have you gotten interested in the Russian language? *Опьянение* is written with a soft sign.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр I've had an interest for a long time. And I found your site a year and a half later. And I started studying it to reduce the number of mistakes when communicating with someone. Most people don't care if there are errors or not, but I like to write with fewer errors. Now I almost don't sit in social networks, but I still continue to study.

Comment: In English, it's much more common to use *hardly* rather than *almost not*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+hardly%2Calmost+isn%27t+%2B+almost+is+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Да я ваш профиль смотрел, видел, что вы, кроме русского, ещë английский, французский и немецкий изучаете. А я через переводчик писал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире нужно. Знак *запятая — тире* ставится для приложений. Ещё: по структуре предложения кажется, что там объясняется причина, почему человек не пришёл. Тогда стоит разделить союз.

*Вчера — в пятницу — я не пришëл из-за того, что был занят.*

*Я не пришел вчера — в пятницу, — когда вы уже приехали, из-за того, что был занят.* (Чтобы запятая была, я вставил *когда*-оборот.)

Пример с приложением:

*Мой **друг-рыбак — старый хрыщ,** с которым я отроду знаком, вчера окуня выловил.*

Comment: Быстренько принимаете!   Никто ваши вопросы прочитать не успел. А я вот не согласна.  Вчера в пятницу, сегодня в пятницу – что это за сочетания? Здесь уточнение в обоих случаях.

Comment: Вчера в пятницу я не пришëл из-за того, что был занят. А сегодня в субботу я приду. Интересные предложения.  Я бы все-таки обособила уточняющий оборот.